# Microdata и продвижение

Tags: html, html5, microdata

Подскажите, собрался переводить сайт на html5 и встал вопрос - реально ли влияет на продвижение и/или улучшение индексации сайта Microdata?
Так же вот простой пример - а какие правильно использовать атрибуты, если страница, грубо говоря, состоит из title и content?

```
<div class="first" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event/" >
<h1 itemprop="?????"> Мой заголовок</h1>
<span class="mycl" itemprop="?????">Контент</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Точно не могу сказать в плане seo - вроде везде пишут что влияет положительно. Но с микроразметкой сайт в выдаче будет выглядеть красивее - например хлебные крошки, рейтинг статьи, фильма итп.
Подробнее про микроразметку можно почитать [здесь](http://phpbl.ru/raznoye/mikrorazmetka.html)

По поводу последнего вопроса - можно использовать мета тэги для разметки. Например

```
<meta itemprop="url" content="http://mysite.ru/page1.html">
```